# Функция, которая убирает все лишние символы, и оставляет только цифры

Tags: php, функции

Переменная на сайте содержит номер телефона в виде +7 (999) 000-11-22.
Есть ли какая-нибудь функция в PHP для того, чтобы привести номер к виду 79990001122?

Comment: http://solutioncatalog.a505.ru/sol/show?id=298
http://habrahabr.ru/post/102352/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Будет работать, если в строке нет многобайтовых символов (русских букв, грубо говоря). Что будет с многобайтовыми - затрудняюсь сказать (хотя, скорее всего, будут появляться левые цифры).

```
function stripChars($text) {
    $res = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
         if (intval($text[$i]) > 1 || $text[$i] === '0') {
             $res .= $text[$i];
         }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Альтернативный подход, но более затратный (хотя не факт) - регулярки.

```
$text = preg_replace('#\D#u', '', $text);
```

Comment: А что означает первый параметр #\D#u и второй пустой?

Comment: preg_replace заменяет все в аргументе 3, совпадающее с регулярным выражением в аргументе 1 содержимым аргумента 2. В данном случае все нецифровые символы (\d соответствует символам 0-9, \D - всему, кроме 0-9) заменяются на пустую строку (строка без символов тоже является строкой). # - это разделители регулярного выражения, обычно используют обычные слеши, u - флаг работы с юникодом. Более подробно об этом всем можно почитать в разделе регулярных выражений в документации.

Answer (score 2):

Еще, еще, еще..

```
/**
 * Removes all characters except digits
 * 
 * @param string $value String to be filtered
 * @param bool   $toInt Whether or not to convert the result to an integer
 *
 * @return string|int Filtered $value
 */
function crazyFilter($value, $toInt = FALSE) {
    $result = array_filter(str_split($value), function($item) {
        $allowed = array_map('strval', range(0, 9));
        return in_array($item, $allowed);
    });

    $result = implode($result);

    if ($toInt) {
        $result = (int)$result;
    }

    return $result;
}

$value = '-jd12XX345-+*41467.8,90a@!&#';
var_dump(crazyFilter($value));       // string '1234541467890' (length=13)
var_dump(crazyFilter($value, TRUE)); // int 2147483647
```